# pyInstaller and Django : Couldn't import Django

Tags: python, django, import, pyinstaller

I am working on an django application and have kind of finish coding it.
This app is designed to be used by someone else and as she isn't so familiar with command line or so, i would like to create an executable (with pyInstaller) that start the localhost server and open the page on a browser (I don't nee to deploy it online or so, the localhost is sufficient).

To do so, I've created a python script that calls the command
`python3 manage.py runserver`
and then open the localhost page in a browser.

I then called the command
`pyinstaller myApp.py` 
(with myApp.py the python script containing the 2 commands above) and then also the command
`pyinstaller TestMACB2.spec`
(I'm not sure I need this command but anyway I now have an executable that tries to run those two commands).

The opening of the web page works well but I dont know why for the command to start the server, i have this error:
`Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`

I do have django installed and when I start the server with the command in a terminal, it works fine.

This is myApp.py script :

```
import os
import sys 
import webbrowser


os.system('python3 <full_path_to_manage.py> runserver')

webbrowser.open('http://127.0.0.1:8000/MACB')
```

Do you have an idea how to fix it ?

I also have another little issue : for the command `os.system('python3 <full_path_to_manage.py> runserver')` i must specify the full path. If i try something like `./manage.py` or `./../../../manage.py` it says it cant find this file. but in the second case it should work. do you know how I could avoid using the full path ?

Thank you for the time you took reading this!

Comment: PyInstaller attempts to detect which modules are required for your program and includes them in the executable. Because your `myApp.py` script does not import your application or Django then PyInstaller does not include that library. Either tell PyInstaller which modules are required and include them, or redesign your starting application to include all requirements.

Comment: @AdamMcKay Hey, thank for your answer ! I've tried to include django by adding the line ``ìmport django```in the ```myApp.py```but it doesn't work either. Is that what you meant or you meant something else ?

Comment: Yes, try the [recipe](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Executable-From-Django) from their documentation.